# Send Update to Repeating BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, repeatingalarm, android-intentservice

I have something like the following for initiating an `IntentService` via repeated calls to a `BroadcastReceiver` to poll for server updates:

```
AlarmManager pollManager;
Intent pollIntent;
PendingIntent pollPendingIntent;

...

pollIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActionUpdateReceiver.class);
pollIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
pollIntent.putExtra(RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
pollIntent.putExtra(USER, accountId);

// This is the crux of my question
pollIntent.putExtra(SOMETHING_THAT_UPDATES, updatingThing);

pollPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), ACTION_REQUEST,
        pollIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
pollManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        POLL_INTERVAL, pollPendingIntent);
```

In terms of polling the server and using a `ResultReceiver` for obtaining server updates, the above approach works well. However, I need to provide some feedback to the polling service in order to alter my update queries.

How should I provide feedback to the polling service? If updated queries are called for, do I just need to cancel the current alarm and set-up the intents again? Is there a better approach than canceling?

Comment: your question is not clear..  what is "provide feedback"?   what is polling server?

Comment: What exactly is unclear? The polling service is the `IntentService` invoked by the `BroadcastReceiver` as specified. Feedback is, well, feedback. It's feedback to update the queries used by the polling service, and it depends upon execution outside of the repeating polling service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem ... I think you want to change the value on "updatingThing" somewhere in your project after the alarm manager setup above
if this is your problem check this solution 
for setup alarm in the code above just replace this line

```
pollIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActionUpdateReceiver.class);
```

by this

```
pollIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ActionUpdateReceiver.class);
```

and for PendingIntent also

```
pollPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ACTION_REQUEST,
        pollIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and put this code where you want to feedback your update

```
AlarmManager pollManager;
Intent pollIntent;
PendingIntent pollPendingIntent;

...

pollIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ActionUpdateReceiver.class);
pollIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
pollIntent.putExtra(RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
pollIntent.putExtra(USER, accountId);


pollIntent.putExtra(SOMETHING_THAT_UPDATES, updatingThing); // your update here

pollPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ACTION_REQUEST,
        pollIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
pollManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        POLL_INTERVAL, pollPendingIntent);
```

Comment: I don't think that the getApplicationContext() is necessary; getActivity() works fine as a Context. Also, this doesn't appear any different to me than just cancelling the Intents as a said before, which is what I did. Anyway, that approach seems to work, so I guess it's the answer after all.